# Are getter functions necessary for Protractor element locators

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

When using PageObjects for Protractor e2e tests, should you use getter functions for the element locator variables instead of having variables?

example:

```
public loginButton: ElementFinder = $('#login-submit');
public loginUsername: ElementFinder = $('#login-username');
```

Or should you use a getter function in the Page Object like this:

```
public get loginButton(): ElementFinder {
  return $('#login-submit');
}

public get loginUsername(): ElementFinder {
  return $('#login-username');
}
```

Is one approach better than another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No getters needed, since protractor ElementFinder and ElementArrayFinder objects are lazy - no any searching for this element will be done until you will try to call some methods on them. Actually thats also a reason why you don't need to use await for protractor element search methods:

```
const button = $('button') // no await needed, no getter needed
console.log('Element is not yet tried to be searched on the page')
await button.click() // now we are sending 2 commands one by one - find element and second - do a click on found element.
```

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder

> ElementFinder can be used to build a chain of locators that is used to find an element. An ElementFinder does not actually attempt to find the element until an action is called, which means they can be set up in helper files before the page is available.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to use either but if you're going to transform or do something else to your element, then the getter function would be better in my opinion since that's the reason why we utilize mutators in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure which method is more convenient, if there is one.
I've been using protractor for a bit longer than 1 year now, and I always stored locators in variables.
What I'd normally do is:

```
const button = element(by.buttonText('Button'));
```

Then I'd create a function for interacting with the element:

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

const clickElement = async (element) => {
    await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element));
    await element.click();
};
```

Finally, use it:

```
await clickElement(button);
```

Of course I store the locators and functions in a page object, and invoking/calling them in the spec file. It's been working great so far.